# TObjectIntMap.get() returns 0 if null Trove

Tags: java, null, hashmap, integer, trove4j

I am using trove library to create hash maps

```
http://trove.starlight-systems.com/
```

The class I am using is TObjectIntMap in which I had to use the function get.
The issue is that get returns 0 if two cases

1- If the value of the specified key is zero

2- If the key does not exist

For example in the following code

```
TObjectIntMap<String> featuresMap = new TObjectIntHashMap<String>();

        if(String.valueOf(featuresMap.get("B")) == null)
            System.out.println("NULL");
        else 
            System.out.println("NotNull");


        System.out.println(featuresMap.get("B"));
```

The program will print the following

1- NotNull: because it gets zero. Although the key "B" has not been set

2- Zero: The return of featuresMap.get("B") is zero instead of null.

I have checked their documentation in the link below and it was a mistake that they solved. So get actually return zero instead of null because int cannot be null.

```
https://bitbucket.org/robeden/trove/issue/43/incorrect-javadoc-for-tobjectintmapget
```

Now my question is: How to differentiate between a zero and Null in this case. Is their any way around to address this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try their [containsKey](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/TObjectIntMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) method. If the value comes back 0, use that method to check if the map contains the key - if it does, then the key's value really is 0. If it doesn't, then the key is not set.

Comment: But do I really need to ckeck if return zero. I can only check "contains key", right ?

Comment: You get to pick the order. If it does contain a key, you might still need to get its value, in case you're interested in non-zero values. Glad I could help!

Comment: You can also adjust the "noEntryValue" (the value that's returned) by configuration from the constructor. So, for example, if -1 is a better value for you, that could be configured. See: http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TObjectIntHashMap.html#TObjectIntHashMap(int, float, int)